# Cometd maxInterval configurations per session

Tags: java, comet, cometd

Is there a way to configure the cometd server maxInterval per user session ?

https://github.com/cometd/cometd-documentation/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/java_server_configuration.adoc

maxInterval 10000   The maximum period of time, in milliseconds, that the server waits for a new long poll from a client before that client is considered invalid and is removed

We wanted to configure this on case basis depending on the client types? In scenarios where there cold be patchy network wanted to configure this to a higher value and use a lesser value in other scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to set `maxInterval` for each `ServerSession` has been introduced with the fix for [issue #844](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/issues/844).

This is available since CometD 4.0.4.

See also [the javadoc](https://docs.cometd.org/current4/apidocs/org/cometd/bayeux/server/ServerSession.html#setMaxInterval(long)).

Comment: This worked. Is there a recommendation around when to set this ? Or can be set anytime based on use case ?

Comment: `maxInterval` can be set at any time. The new value will become effective just before the server returns a `/meta/connect` reply to the client. This means that if a server has returned a `/meta/connect` reply with `maxInterval = 10 s`, the server will schedule the session expiration after 10 s. If the `maxInterval` is changed meanwhile, it won't have effect. But if the client sends a `/meta/connect` message the server will cancel the expiration and (eventually) reply to the `/meta/connect`, taking into account the new `maxInterval` value.